# Center ul in cell in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page that uses Bootstrap 3. In this web page, I'm trying to center a `ul` within a `col-xs-12`. Currently, in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7ifzWwjknW), I have the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 center-block" style="background-color:grey;">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><div class="item"></div></li>
        <li><div class="item"></div></li>
        <li><div class="item"></div></li>
        <li><div class="item"></div></li>
        <li><div class="item"></div></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As shown, the `ul` is left-aligned within the `div`. How do I center the `ul` in the `div`. If that's not possible, how do I horizontally center a list of horizontally laid out items?

Answer (score 13):

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li><div class="item"></div></li>
  <li><div class="item"></div></li>
  <li><div class="item"></div></li>
  <li><div class="item"></div></li>
  <li><div class="item"></div></li>
</ul>

.list-inline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try adding properties `display:flex` and `justify-content:center` to div

Answer (score 1):

Just use Bootstrap `text-center` which works to center inline elements. No extra CSS is needed.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:grey;">
      <ul class="list-inline text-center">
        <li><div class="item"></div></li>
        <li><div class="item"></div></li>
        <li><div class="item"></div></li>
        <li><div class="item"></div></li>
        <li><div class="item"></div></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/PIVeDmWHbz

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">    
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 center-block align" style="background-color:grey;">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><div class="item">aaa</div></li>
        <li><div class="item">vvv</div></li>
        <li><div class="item">eee</div></li>
        <li><div class="item">eee</div></li>
        <li><div class="item">eee</div></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

```
<style>.align ul{position:relative;left:50%;float:left;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

for horizontally center you can use the following code:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 center-block" style="background-color:grey;">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><div class="item">aaa</div></li>
        <li><div class="item">vvv</div></li>
        <li><div class="item">eee</div></li>
        <li><div class="item">eee</div></li>
        <li><div class="item">eee</div></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

`<style>
.center-block ul{position:relative;left:50%;float:left;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;}
.center-block li {position:relative;right:50%;float:left;margin:0;list-style:none}
</style>`